# Reading in text file to a struct array

Tags: arrays, file-io, struct

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


// user struct
struct userInfo {
    string username;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string favTVshow;

}; 

// create text file with each person's information
void dataBase(){
    ofstream dataFile("db.txt");

dataFile << "8\ngboss\nGriffin\nBoss\nHow I Met Your Mother\nechill\nEdwina\nCarol\nGossip Girl\nestone\nEmma\nStone\nScrubs\njcasablancas\nJulian\nCasablancas\nLost\nrobflew\nRob\nFlewelling\nWorkaholics\ncwoodsum\nCam\nWoodsum\nGlee\nrydogfav\nRyan\nFavero\nHomeland\nfishmans\nSam\nFishman\nEntourage\n";

     dataFile.close();
}

// read in database text file to an array
void dataBase_toArray(){
    userInfo userArray[8]
    string line;
    int loop = 0;

ifstream dataFile("db.txt");

if (dataFile.is_open()){
    while (getline(dataFile,line))
    {
        userArray[loop].username = line;
        userArray[loop].firstName = line;
        userArray[loop].lastName = line;
        userArray[loop].favTVshow = line;
        cout << userArray[loop].username << endl;
        loop++;
    }
    dataFile.close();
}
else cout << "Can't open file" << endl;

}

// main function
int main() {

userInfo userArray[8];

dataBase();
dataBase_toArray();



}
```

So this is my code I am trying to read in this text file into an array of struct. However, when I try to cout the username of each user, it doesn't work. It just prints out the first 8 lines of my text file. How can I fix this and have it input the text to the struct array and output just the username of each of the 8 users?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
while (getline(dataFile,line))
{
    userArray[loop].username = line;
    userArray[loop].firstName = line;
    userArray[loop].lastName = line;
    userArray[loop].favTVshow = line;
    cout << userArray[loop].username << endl;
    loop++;
}
dataFile.close();
```

The reason you were getting those errors was that **you only had ready the line *once*, hence the values of `username`, `firstname`, `lastname` and `favTVshow` were being assigned to the same value that was stored when getline was run.**

I propose the following (which is a bit reminiscent of C's fscanf):

```
while (getline(dataFile,line1) && getline(dataFile, line2) && getline(dataFile, line3) && getline(dataFile, line4))
{
    userArray[loop].username = line1;
    userArray[loop].firstName = line2;
    userArray[loop].lastName = line3;
    userArray[loop].favTVshow = line4;
    ++loop;
}
```

where:

```
string line;
```

has been replaced by this:

```
string line1, line2, line3, line4;
```

This way, it **ensures** that four lines were successfully read (which is the number of elements in the struct), and that each has been assigned values which can now be **properly assigned** to each element in your Array of structs.

Now, ideally, this isn't the best way to do it - **you could have used vectors and the like**, but from your problem set, I kept it in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first line in the file ("8") is the number of users:

```
int n;
dataFile >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    getline(dataFile,line);
    userArray[loop].username = line;
    getline(dataFile,line);
    userArray[loop].firstName = line;
    getline(dataFile,line);
    userArray[loop].lastName = line;
    getline(dataFile,line);
    userArray[loop].favTVshow = line;
    cout << userArray[loop].username << endl;
    loop++;
}
```